# A test fixture database to experiment on performance tuning?

Tags: optimization

I would like to learn the basics of database performance tuning, and for myself I learn things faster if I can do hands-on to practise the learning materials.

For the performance tuning, it seems that the only way to test out the effectiveness of a tweaking you made is to test on a DB server containing a large amount of data, and compare the time taken to run some sort of test before and after the tweaking.

So, is there a readily downloadable database image or SQL scripts (preferably for SQL Server and Oracle) or something, so to **experiment** on the performance tuning immediately? Like the data is arranged in some way that a query will be run very slowly right after the database is set up, and after you did some optimization the query will have noticeable improvement on its execution time.

Comment: The database is only one part in performance tuning - modelling, indexing, querying, server setup and other factors come into play, depending on how deep you want to dig. My advice is to ask your DBA or sysadmin for a development or dedicated sandbox environment of some database you have at work - that way, you can relate to the contents and needs of the database, and you'll have a more practical application of stuff you learn. :)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has Contoso BI Demo Dataset https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18279 which is big enough to see the difference when  plaing with indexes, queries etc.